# Subscring to events in an isolated WPF add-in

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, remoting, maf

I have an isolated WPF add-in. The addin gets a reference to the type that exposes the event. Since addin is isolated in a specific appdomain, the host knows nothing about the addin's DLL, or the types stored there.

Contract:

```
    [AddInContract]
    public interface IAddInContract: IContract
    {
        void Initialize(IAddInHandler handler);
    }
```

handler is a type that exposes the event, and derives from MarshalByRef, so that the proxy is passed to the addin:

```
    public class AddInHandler : MarshalByRefObject, IAddInHandler 
    {
       public event SelectionChangedEventHandler SelectionChanged;
    }
```

and in the addin we do something like:

```
        public override void Initialize(IAddInHandler handler)
        {
            handler.SelectionChanged += handler_SelectionChanged;
        }
```

However this fails, as it tries (somehow) to pass a reference of the addin to the host application, and since to the host, addin's dll is unknown, it fails to load the type and throws exception. How can I still maintain the isolation, and be able to do something like described above?

Comment: "Fails" how? What exception is actually thrown? Is your add-in type also `MarshalByRef`? Or serializable? Does this question really have anything to do with WPF? Or could you reproduce the same problem in a simple console program? Note that without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably demonstrates the problem, you may have a hard time finding someone willing to take the time to come up with a solution (assuming one exists).

Comment: This seems to be an odd design. Your `AddInHandler` isn't a handler - it's the producer of the events. Seems like this might be backwards.

Answer (score 1):

i had a similar problem and solved it in the following way:

For the Add-In Contract, I didn't used the C# Eventing Pattern using Delegates. I used a "Java-Like" Event Registration Pattern, that means i created an interface with one Method (Interface needs to implement IContract), then i created in the Contract two methods with AddEventHandler and RemoveEventHandler. Both requires an instance of the previously created interface.
In the Adapters, you create an adapter between your delegate and that interface implementation.