# Sending Event from AddIn to Host

Tags: maf, system.addin

I've an AddIn Pipeline and want to send information from AddIn to Host. How could I define events on AddIn and subscribe to these events from Host side?

Actually I've defined two methods in my AddIn contract named Activate/Deactivate and want to send information to host if the specified addin is successfully Activated/Deactivated or not. Host calls these methods on the addin and they work fine, but how could I get the Event that these methods performed as per desire or not.

Comment: I found similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29384383/subscring-to-events-in-an-isolated-wpf-add-in 
Lorentz's solution seems it may work, but he didn't provide sample code

Comment: I got a concrete example here: https://www.sommercorn.com/Blog/Post/2016/3/18/4/net-addin-framework-with-backwards-compatibility-part-2--events#2016